# How to use `asRight` to create Either instance with cats

Tags: scala, either, scala-cats, scala-repl

I am trying to create an instance of `Either` using `asRight` in REPL:

```
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._ 

scala> val x = "xxx".asRight
<console>:20: error: value asRight is not a member of String
       val x = "xxx".asRight
                 ^

scala> import cats.syntax.either._
import cats.syntax.either._

scala> val x = "xxx".asRight
<console>:23: error: value asRight is not a member of String
       val x = "xxx".asRight
                 ^
```

What's wrong with the code above ?  Is it possible to use `asRight` in REPL ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EitherIdOps` which includes `asRight` and `asLeft` ops was first introduced in cats 0.9.0 (the latest release at the time of writing). You are most likely using an earlier version.

```
scala> import cats._, implicits._
import cats._
import implicits._

scala> "xxx".asRight
res0: Either[Nothing,String] = Right(xxx)

scala> "xxx".asRight[Int]
res1: Either[Int,String] = Right(xxx)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You are right. I was using an earlier version.